# combine like and not like in regexp_like for optimizing hive query in Amazon Athena

Tags: hive, amazon-athena

I need to rewrite hive query in an optimized way. The where clause  of my query is

`WHERE counters is NOT null
        AND info LIKE '%sub-page-type=ext-rlol_%'
        AND info LIKE '%page-type=Faceout%'
        AND info NOT LIKE '%page-type=FaceoutRAW%'`

The athena doc says that we can optimize hive queries https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/ . Please refer to point 9.

Can someone help me write a more optimized query. This query is timing out ( more than 30 mins)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a single regular expression and by using positive/negative `lookahead patterns`. In theory this would be reading 3 times less the textual data:

```
WHERE 
counters is NOT null
AND info RLIKE 
'(?=.*sub-page-type=ext-rlol_)(?=.*page-type=Faceout)(?!.*page-type=FaceoutRAW)'
```

EDIT:
Apparently your amazon documentation states your are not using HIVE but presto. Then the same apply while being an other syntax:

```
WHERE 
counters is NOT null
AND  regexp_like (info,
'(?=.*sub-page-type=ext-rlol_)(?=.*page-type=Faceout)(?!.*page-type=FaceoutRAW)')
```